# NHibernate proxy class, what should I choose?

Tags: nhibernate

What proxy class is best?

1. NHibernate.ByteCode.LinFu.ProxyFactoryFactory
2. NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory
3. NHibernate.ByteCode.Spring.ProxyFactoryFactory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already used #1 & #2 and they behave equally apparently, no differences detected.

Extracted from nhforge.org blog:

> We are
>   using LinFu without a special reason
>   even if I have the impression that
>   LinFu give us a very little
>   performance improvement. For who are
>   using NHibernate without an IoC
>   framework LinFu.DynamicProxy is more
>   than enough.
>
> For who are working with
>   Castle.ActiveRecord and/or
>   Castle.Windsor, obviously, the best
>   choice is Castle.DynamicProxy2 (mean
>   NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory).

http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/11/09/nh2-1-0-bytecode-providers.aspx

Comment: One *gotcha* I've come across; the Linfu provider seems to break equality on the S#arp architecture base objects, so I'd advise using the castle provider if you happen to make use of this framework.

Comment: No problem, further details can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/linfu/issues/detail?id=34#c0